# Trying to allow user to select birthday - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form in a Django project, and I want the user to enter his birthday so that I can be saved in the database and used later in the project...

I have a model and I want to create a Modelform which will ask for the date and then format it and save it in the database. I have been trying to figure this out for 3 days and can't get it to work... I have had to delete my database file around 5 times because it was not working and messing up the database...

WHen the user submits the form, the return is three separate items which include dob_month, dob_day, dob_year with the correct date information

Here is what I have so far.

models.py file

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45)  # user
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='state')
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)  # user
    privacy = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)  # user
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server
```

Here is the forms.py file:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    split_choices = (('1', 'public'),
                     ('2', 'private'))
    privacy = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=split_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'city', 'state', 'phone', 'privacy']
```

here is the view.py file (the specific def that processes the form...)

```
def profile_setup(request):
    if 'username' not in request.session:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        # the following is just going to grab the currently logged in user and
        # save the profile information to the appropriate user
        username = request.session['username']
        currentUser = User.objects.get(username = username)
        # the following is the provessing for the form where the user entered
        # the profile informaiton
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                first_name = cd['first_name']
                last_name = cd['last_name']
                dob_month = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_month")
                dob_day = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_day")
                dob_year = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_year")
                city = cd['city']
                state = cd['state']
                phone = cd['phone']
                privacy = cd['privacy']
                # this is the new record that is going to be created and saved
                new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                    user = currentUser,
                    first_name = first_name,
                    last_name = last_name,
                    dob_month = dob_month,
                    dob_day = dob_day,
                    dob_year = dob_year,
                    city = city,
                    state = state,
                    phone = phone,
                    privacy = privacy,
                )
                return redirect('home_page')
        else:
            # this is what is going to be saved into the html file and used to
            # render the file
            form = ProfileForm()
            message = 'fill out form below'
            parameters = {
                'form':form,
                'currentUser':currentUser,
                'message':message,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/profile_setup.html', parameters)
```

**UPDATED SECTION **

so lets say i have a model like the following:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True)
    count = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=GROUP_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    reference_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

andi have a model form like the following:

```
class CreateGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name', 'count', 'description']
```

and the user submits the following form:

```
name : omar jandali
count : 5
description : random group
```

then i can process the form in the following way:

```
form = CreateGroupForm(request.POST, instance=new_group)
new_group = Group(
    name = name,
    description = desciption,
    count = count,
    status = status,
)
```

or would i still have to assign the cleaned data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do so much work to process the form. With Django Model forms most of the work is done for you. If you want to create a new record make sure you add `instance` to your form tag like so:

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance= new_profile)
```

Then before method.request add:

```
new_profile = Profile(
    user = ...
    created = ...
    )
```

where '...' is the value you want associated with that form instance.

get rid of `new_profile = Profile.objects.create(...`

Basically you need to set the values that are not provided by the user in the specific instance and then call them when you instantiate the form.

Comment: So for any model form, I can just create an instance of it and save it without having to process it like am doing right now.... can you look at the updated section of my post and tell me I can do something like it for any of my forms.... @jonin

Comment: Because you are using a Modelform with fields for name, discription, and count, there is no need to add name, description, and count to the new_group. You just need values for status and reference_code. also make sure that your form tag comes after your new_group not before or it won't work.